# Where or with like groupings in typeORM

Tags: javascript, typeorm

How to have this in typeORM?

```
SELECT id,name,address,sex,birthday,area FROM users WHERE area = 2 and (name LIKE '%params%' OR address like '%params%')
```

i tried something like this but it does not filter properly.

```
const { DataSource, Equal, Like } = require("typeorm");

const data = await connetion.getReporsitory("Users").find({
   where: [
      {area: Equal(params) },
      {name: Like(`%${params}%`) },
      {address: Like(`%${params}%`) }
   ]
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't this ( `{area: Equal(params) }` ) be: `{area: 2 }` ?

Comment: sorry yeah it should be`{area: 2}` but sill it produces `WHERE area = 2 OR...` not `WHERE area = 2 AND...`

Answer (score 0):

found it, i used Raw function of typeORM

```
const { DataSource, Equal, Like, Raw } = require("typeorm");
const data = await connetion.getReporsitory("Users").find({
   where: {
      area: Raw(2+`AND (Users.name LIKE '%${params}%' OR Users.address LIKE '%${params}%')`)
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you add multiple queries with AND operator.
[Documentation](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/find-options)

```
const { DataSource, Equal, Like } = require("typeorm");
const data = await connetion.getReporsitory("Users").find({
   where: {
     area: Equal(params),
     name: Like(`%${params}%`),
     address: Like(`%${params}%`) 
   }
});
```

Comment: This will result to `WHERE area = 2 AND name LIKE '%%' AND  address LIKE '%%'` and not `WHERE area = 2 AND (name LIKE '%%' OR address LIKE '%%')`